# Parsing Javascript Variable into php query

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I am newbie in php and still learn javascript function.

I have a problem with, include javascript variable into php query.

I want to create transaction code according count of part code which have different type. then i must get value with count.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getCode(){
    var v =document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
    <?php 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)+1 as count FROM TB_TRANSACTION where part_code = "<script>v;</script>"");
    $i=-1;
    while ($code_part = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
       $i++;
       ?>
       var getPartCode = <? echo $code_part['count'];?>;
       var x = document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
       var y = document.forms["form1"]["location_code"].value;
       var z = document.forms["form1"]["date"].value;
       var a = (getPartCode + '/'+x +'/'+ y +'/'+ z);
       document.forms["form1"]["invent_code"].value = a;
       <?
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

The result like that `1/CPU/JKT/2013`

I call that function with `button onClick="getCode()"` no submit.

Anyone can help me.

Comment: You can't combine `php` and `js` code in one block and expect variables to be available in both. You can learn it [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/)

Comment: Hint --> use the "tools -> view source" option in your browser. php can only be used for generating the html/jscript page. Once generated php is done and gone.

Comment: you're opening yourself to any kind of possible vulnerability and security holes with that code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Thanks All for your attention.. I use ajax and post with json. I found the answer in..  [link] here (http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/simple-ajax-post-example-with-php-codeIgniter-framework-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it by the way you tried.There are two better ways to do it

1. Use `Ajax`.
2. Use Cookies

   The best way here is to use Ajax. Here, iam using `javascript` and `ajax`.And i am creating a new file to create response(say newfile.php) Try this,

   ```
   function getCode(){
           var v =document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
           var x = document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
           var y = document.forms["form1"]["location_code"].value;
           var z = document.forms["form1"]["date"].value;
           var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {   // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       var getPartCode=xmlhttp.responseText;  //Getting the response from php file
       var a = (getPartCode + '/'+x +'/'+ y +'/'+ z); 
       document.forms["form1"]["invent_code"].value = a;
       }
     }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","newFile.php?q="+v,true);  //Sending request to newfile.php 
   xmlhttp.send();
           }
   </script>
   ```

**newfile.php**

```
<?php
$value = $_GET["q"];  //getting the value sent through tthe ajax request
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)+1 as count FROM TB_TRANSACTION where part_code = '$value'");
   $i=-1;
    while ($code_part = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $i++;
    echo $code_part['count'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: could do indent your code? Even if i know what you are trying to do it's kind of difficult to read it

Comment: raduns, I use code igniter framework. i dont know how to load view .. in thats script xmlhttp.open("GET","newFile.php?q="+v,true); Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Best Method is `Ajax`

Otherwise Use Cookies

For Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
</script>

<?php 
   $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];
   echo $phpVar;
?>
```

Your code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getCode(){
    var v =document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
     document.cookie = "cookieName="+v;
    <?php 
   $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)+1 as count FROM TB_TRANSACTION where part_code = '$phpVar'");
    $i=-1;
    while ($code_part = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $i++;
    ?>
    var getPartCode = <? echo $code_part['count'];?>;
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
    var y = document.forms["form1"]["location_code"].value;
    var z = document.forms["form1"]["date"].value;
    var a = (getPartCode + '/'+x +'/'+ y +'/'+ z);
    document.forms["form1"]["invent_code"].value = a;
    <?
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Updated

Check this

```
function getCode(){
var v = 12;
document.cookie = "cookieName="+v;
var getPartCode = <?php echo $_COOKIE['cookieName']; ?>
alert(getPartCode);
}
```

Comment: I have follow your (Nathan Srivi) instruction to use cookie, but still not working. I try call that cookie with javascript alert still not alert show.
The Script Like This..

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    
    function getCode(){
    var v = document.forms["form1"]["part_code"].value;
    document.cookie = "cookieName="+v;
    <?php 
    $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];
    ?>
    var getPartCode = <? echo $phpVar;?>
    alert(getPartCode);
    </script>